# Give permission to view files

Tags: permissions, webserver

I am new with servers and I started learning about Cloud servers. My server has Debian.

I installed apache, php, and vsftpd and I added users with `adduser <user>`.

Then I gave permission:

```
ln -s /var/www www
chown -R <user> /var/www 
chmod -R 755 /var/www**
```

Now, I logged in through FTP and I went to the directory `/var/www` where `index.html` and `test.php` were. I deleted both files and upload another `test.html` file. When I try to access it I get:

```
You don't have permission to access /test.html on this server.
```

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the permissions on the file so your web server can read it again - you deleted the version with correct permissions.

Comment: No. If I do that, the next file I upload still has permission 600

Comment: chmod so that "other" users have read access to the file, or change the owner to the server user, and make sure the permissions allow the owner to read the file.